# Merging rows based on values contained in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to merge together based on a list of indexes

```
| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | [1,2,3]        |
| 2        | [4,5,6]        |
| 3        | [7,8]          |
| 4        | [2,3]          |
```

`list = [[1,4]]`
Expected output

```
| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | [1,2,3]        |
| 2        | [4,5,6]        |
| 3        | [7,8]          |
```

This happens because we took the list that is bigger (i.e. index 1)

Comment: In `L = [[1,4]]` is only one nested list? Nested lists has only 2 values? Or possible more? If more lists should ne overlap like  `L = [[1,4], [4,2]` ?

Comment: @jezrael thanks - to clarify, is will be a nested list, but the elements in the nested list are NOT expected to overlap. For example in this scenario, you could have `[[1,4],[2,3]]`

Comment: So need answer bellow? Remove subsets?

Comment: hmmm, `[[1,4],[2,3]]` means merge `A=[1,4]` and `A=[2,3]` ? So ouput is different like in question?

Comment: Because ouput in question is `[[1,4],[2],[3]]` - `2,3` are not merged

Comment: Also `I want to merge together based on a list of indexes` - it means `L = [[1,4]]` or lists in column `B` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the subsets.

For this you must use a small loop. To increase performance you can first convert the lists to sets, then sort them by decreasing length.

```
def remove_subsets(ser):
    # convert the lists to sets and sort by decreasing length
    s = (ser.apply(set)
            .sort_values(key=lambda x: x.str.len(), ascending=False)
        )
    drop = []
    keep = []
    # for each item
    for idx, s in s.items():
        # if a previous item is a superset, drop it
        if any(s.issubset(s2) for s2 in keep):
            drop.append(idx)
        # else, keep it and add to the list of supersets
        else:
            keep.append(s)
    # return indices to drop
    return drop

out = df.drop(remove_subsets(df['B']))
```

output:

```
   A          B
0  1  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  [4, 5, 6]
2  3     [7, 8]
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this?